# PHP Undefined Index when handling checkboxes with MySQLi

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, mysqli

I have some PHP code that checks a MYSQL database using MySQLi and outputs all of the 'stock' type into a form with a while statement:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT name FROM items WHERE type='stock' ORDER BY name");
echo '<table style="text-align:center;"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Use</th>';

while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo '<tr><form action="chooseProduct" method="POST"><td>' . $item['name'] . '</td><td><input type="number" name="amount[]"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="stock[]" value="' . $item['name'] . '"></td></tr>';

    }

echo '<tr><td rowspan="3" colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Select"></td></tr></form></table>';
```

I then need to be able to select the stock that I wish to use and click on select to send me to the "chooseProduct" page where there I should then be able to use the data 'amount' and 'stock' in an array form. However, when using POST to retrieve these values on the chooseProduct page by doing the following:

```
$stock = $_POST['stock'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
```

I get the error as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined index: stock in C:\xampp\htdocs\production\chooseProduct\index.php on line 59

Notice: Undefined index: amount in C:\xampp\htdocs\production\chooseProduct\index.php on line 60
```

The checkbox is definitely checked, so what could be causing this error?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: @JohnConde array(0) { }

Answer (score 2):

Your form tag is inside of your loop. This is creating an invalid mess of open forms on your page. This is almost certainly causing your form to submit invalid data or nothing at all. Move that opening `<form>` tag outside of your loop to fix this.

Comment: This is definitely helpful, thanks. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Does your form have a closing `</form>` tag? Are you sure the rest of your HTML is valid?

Comment: The form closes in the last echo. I've read over the HTML and I'm reasonably sure it is valid as it outputs what I expect on the page visually. However, I haven't used arrays and checkboxes with forms, so I'm not sure if I'm using it right here.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_POST)` still show `array(0) { }`? If so there is still an HTML error somewhere. I would try to simplify the page if you can and see if that helps any.

Comment: Yes, it does. There isn't really anywhere to simplify the page, I know that the rest of the code on the page works fine and shouldn't be interfering with the code that is producing the error.

Comment: You might need to post the HTML of your page for review then.

Comment: Probably not the best place to put it, but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/2tvd7/

Comment: What we need to see is the final HTML generated by your PHP.

Comment: Take the form out of your table. Put the opening tag before the opening table tag and the closing tag after the closing table tag.

Comment: Done, though there was no noticeable difference in the result (the error still remains): http://jsfiddle.net/Y6hYk/

Comment: Your first table row lack a closing `</tr>` tag. Try adding that and see if it helps.

Comment: Try fixing your doctype which is incorrect: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You're also missing your opening `<html>` tag. Closing one, too.

Comment: I've put in the opening and closing tags, but fixing the doctype broke the styling of the page so I haven't included that (though I noticed that didn't have an effect on the error so I don't think that should be too much of a problem anyway).

Comment: You need to fix all of your HTML errors. Run it through [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and fix all of them. There's just too much wrong to effectively diagnose this.

Comment: The only HTML error according to the validator was that the submit button had a rowspan of 3, which I removed. The other errors resolve around the navigation divs which don't actually need to be fixed as they work as intended and don't effect the form code.

Comment: Are you sure they don't affect the form code? One error in HTML can break other places on the page.

Comment: The error about the navigation divs is that the same div name is used multiple times, but it is opened and closed correctly each time. This shouldn't effect the form code I would have thought?

Comment: You would think but there is no reason for your form submission to be blank, either.

Comment: Unfortunately the navigation divs cannot be changed at this time in the project and so I may end up just removing this feature. Are you sure it isn't anything to do with the way I've handled the checkboxes with arrays though?

Comment: Your post request should not be empty regardless of whether the inputs are arrays or not. Wherever your issue is, it is not in any code I've seen.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like I'll just have to remove this feature then. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've not checked if POST action is already made so there will be warning / notice on assigning it.
try

```
$stock = isset($_POST['stock']) ? $_POST['stock'] : '';
$amount = isset($_POST['amount']) ? $_POST['amount'] : '';
```

Comment: Although this is a good programming practice, it doesn't actually solve their issue.

Comment: Thank you sir :) . I've tried my best to do that, still newbie :)

Comment: That's ok. kudos to you for following good programming practices and for trying to help others. :)